# Improper definite integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}(x + k)^\alpha dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

I am unsure how to calculate the following definite integral:
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}(x + k)^{\alpha}dx,$$
where $k > 0$ and $\alpha$ is a real number. I tried integrating by parts and also a few things with the Gamma function, but I am not getting anywhere. Maybe some slick trick with contour integration? Any help will be highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: wh do you think it exists in closed form at all?

Comment: You can express it with an infinite sum using binomial coefficient expansion (with non-natural $n$).

Comment: @N74 Yes, you are right. But that might be very difficult to compute in closed form, I mean to sum up the series. I was hoping for something easier.

Comment: @Alex Correct, I don't know that for sure. That is part of my question.

Comment: I don't think you'll find anything prettier than $$k^\alpha\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha}{n}\frac{\Gamma\left (\frac{n+1}{2}  \right )}{2k^n}$$

Comment: For natural values of *a*, just expand the integrand using the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), and switch the order of summation and integration. The result can be seen [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BEzss.png).